# Getting TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len() In a simple Snake game

Tags: python, pygame

Im creating a snake Pygame with a menu and am fine tuning the bugs and such when I come across the error

IndexError: list index out of range

the error actually appears after I open the tab itself and move the cursor over it

I have a faint idea of what it actually means but I am quite new to python and coding in general so I would appreciate it if someone could explain and show a solution,

thank you very much and here is the code

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import time

pygame.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 102)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
DARKRED = (125, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

screenWidth = 800
screenHeight = 800

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snakeBlock = 10
snakeSpeed = 15

fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",100)
fontStyle = pygame.font.SysFont("ariel", 50)
scoreFont = pygame.font.SysFont("ariel", 35)


def score(score):
    value = scoreFont.render(" Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(value, [50, 50])



def snake(snakeBlock, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [x[0], x[1], snakeBlock, snakeBlock])


def message(msg, colour):
    msg = fontStyle.render(msg, True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(msg, [screenWidth / 20, screenHeight / 2])


def gameLoop():

    gameOver = False
    gameEnd = False
    instructions = False
    game = True
    intro = True
    main = True



    x1 = screenWidth / 2
    y1 = screenHeight / 2

    dx = 0
    dy = 0

    snakeList = []
    snakeLength = 2

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, screenWidth - snakeBlock) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, screenHeight - snakeBlock) / 10.0) * 10.0

    def menu(titles):
        buttonTitleFont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 52)
        selection = []
        rectWidth = 400
        rectHeight = 60
        x = int(screen.get_width()/2 - rectWidth/2)
        y = 450
        length = len(titles)
        num = 0
        hover = False
        # creates the Rects (containers) for the buttons

        for i in range (0,length,1):
            choiceRect = pygame.Rect(x,y,rectWidth,rectHeight)
            selection.append(choiceRect)
            y += 100

            #main loop in menu    
            menu = True
            while menu:    
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        menu = False
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.type ==pygame.MOUSEMOTION:     # if mouse moved
                        hover = False
                        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()     # get the mouse position
                        for i in range (length):            
                            if selection[i].collidepoint((mx,my)):  # check if x,y of mouse is in a button
                                num = i
                                hover = True
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and hover == True:  #if mouse is in button
                        menu = False                                              # and has been clicked

                # draw all buttons                                                                
                for choice in selection:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,choice,0)

                # redraw selected button in another colour
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,selection[num],0)

                # draw all the titles on the buttons
                x = int(screen.get_width()/2 - 150)
                y = 450
                for i in range(0,length,1):
                    buttonTitle = buttonTitleFont.render(titles[i],True,BLACK)
                    screen.blit(buttonTitle,(x,y))
                    y += 100

                pygame.display.update()
            return num

    while main:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
            if event.type ==pygame.QUIT: # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
                main = False         # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop

        while intro:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    main = False
                    intro = False

            screen.fill(BLACK)

            menuMain = ["Launch", "Instructions","QUIT"]

            mainMenu = True
            mainInt = True
            while mainInt:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        main = False
                        intro = False
                        mainInt = False

                screen.fill(BLACK)

                #Centers the rendered tiles
                textTitle = fontTitle.render("Snake", True, GREEN )
                textW = textTitle.get_width()
                textH = textTitle.get_height()
                xTitle = int(screenWidth/2 - textW/2)
                yTitle = int(screenHeight/4 - textH/2)
                screen.blit(textTitle, (xTitle,yTitle))
                pygame.display.update()

                # in the intro, this asks the user where they would like to go
                if mainMenu ==True:
                    choose = menu(menuMain)
                    if choose == 0:
                        menu = False
                        intro = False
                        mainInt = False
                        mainMenu = False
                        game = True
                        screen.fill(BLACK)
                    elif choose ==1:
                        menu = False
                        instructions = True
                        mainMenu = False
                        screen.fill(BLACK)
                        pygame.display.update()
                    else:
                        menu = False
                        main = False
                        intro = False
                        mainInt = False
                        mainMenu = False

        while game: 

            if gameOver == True:
                game = False

            while gameEnd == True:
                screen.fill(DARKRED)
                message("You Lost! Press C to Play Again or Q to Quit", RED)
                score(snakeLength - 1)
                pygame.display.update()

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                            gameOver = True
                            gameEnd = False
                        if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                            gameLoop()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        dx = -snakeBlock
                        dy = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        dx = snakeBlock
                        dy = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        dx = 0
                        dy = -snakeBlock
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        dx = 0
                        dy = snakeBlock

            if x1 >= screenWidth or x1 < 0 or y1 >= screenHeight or y1 < 0:
                gameEnd = True

            x1 += dx
            y1 += dy

            screen.fill(WHITE)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [foodx, foody, snakeBlock, snakeBlock])
            snakeHead = []
            snakeHead.append(x1)
            snakeHead.append(y1)
            snakeList.append(snakeHead)

            if len(snakeList) > snakeLength:
                del snakeList[0]

            for x in snakeList[:-1]:
                if x == snakeHead:
                    gameEnd = True

            snake(snakeBlock, snakeList)
            score(snakeLength - 1)

            pygame.display.update()

            if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
                foodx = round(random.randrange(0, screenWidth - snakeBlock) / 10.0) * 10.0
                foody = round(random.randrange(0, screenHeight - snakeBlock) / 10.0) * 10.0
                snakeLength += 1

            clock.tick(snakeSpeed)

        pygame.quit()
        quit()


gameLoop()
```

Comment: The message is very clear: you are trying to run the `len` function on a variable of type `bool`.  Specifically at `length = len(titles)` since you call `choose = menu(mainMenu)` and `mainMenu` is a boolean type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
            mainMenu = True
            if mainMenu ==True:
                choose = menu(mainMenu)
```

mean that you are passing a `bool` (`True` is a type of `bool`) to your `menu()` function.

This is how the first argument of `menu()` is being used:

```
def menu(titles):
    ...
    length = len(titles)
```

So like the error message says, you're trying to take the length of a boolean (e.g. `len(True)` does not make sense, so you get an error). You'll have to reconcile this on your own, I'm guessing you meant for `main()` to accept a list of menu titles rather than `True` or `False`

Comment: could you take another look this time Im getting a list index out of range error, I would post another question but there is a cooldown And I dont have the time sorry

Comment: There's no way I'll be able to diagnose an error with that little information. The error will come with a line number, just go to that line number and see whether you're trying to access a list index that's greater than or equal to the length of the list; that'd cause an error that you can hopefully fix